# What do these wheel markings mean?

Tags: wheels

I'm trying to sell my old alloy wheels, and I need to know a few crucial sizes (like the bolt diameter and width) to put up an ad. Unfortunately I cannot make heads or tails of these numbers. Here's all that I found written on them:

> C24B6
>   LK 108
>   M 0926 A J
>   7.0JX16H2   A706
>   MIC ZCW
>   ET 45 X P

What I do know about them is that they are 16" in diameter and had 205/55R16 tires on them beforehand. They also use 5 bolts (nuts? logs? not sure on the difference - I'm not a native English speaker)

I've been trying to google, but to no avail. I also made pictures of them and all of the markings are visible there (at least in the full-sized originals). If you wish, you can look at them [here](http://valts.21.lv/problem/disk/).

Comment: Do you know what car they were on?

Comment: My own Volvo S60, year 2004 edition. However I'm not sure if I shouldn't delete the question now, since I already sold them. :P But perhaps the explanation might be of use to someone else. That is, if there is something to explain at all, and all these characters aren't manufacturer-specific.

Comment: Oh, but they aren't original Volvo disks. Judging by the pictures I'd say it's a safe guess that they were made by [Autec](http://www.autec-wheels.de/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know all of those, but the key ones are:

108 will be the PCD (pitch circle diameter - the distance between the bolt holes).

7.0Jx16 will be the size - 7" wide by 16" diameter. H2 means it is of a double hump design.

ET 45 X P will be the offset - how far in or out the wheel sits in relation toh the hub. In this case it will be 45mm, and I'd expect the P to be positive, i.e. the wheel is inset towards the centre of the car.

[This Page](http://www.carbibles.com/tyre_bible_pg4.html) on the car bibles website explains it in much more detail than I can.